# Codeigniter 2 application upgrade plan: PHP and MySQL versions?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, codeigniter, migration

We have to migrate a Codeigniter 2 application from one linux server to another.

The existing server is running CentOS 5, PHP 5.4 (I think) and MySQL 5.0.95.  The new server is currently running CentOS 8, PHP 7.2 and MySQL 8.0.

Obviously it is not as simple as copying over and go live - the tech team we used found that out when the database queries were not working.  Has anyone attempted such a migration or have any ideas of a plan for it?  I know there are migration guides for various steps of PHP and MySQL but I'm looking for fresh eyes and thoughts on how to tackle this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run it in a test server first. See what changes need to be made, make note of them, and change what you can now that will still work under the old server.

Comment: Also check if used 3rd party libraries work with the new versions

Comment: Well you shouldn't have so much problems. As the comments before, set up a test server, a virtual one with vagrant or similar should be enough. Upgrade your application to CI 3 following the guides in the documentation and check for 3rd party integrations. If the queries are returning errors you probably have to update the core mysql libraries, it's not hard. Just update everything following the guides.

Comment: There's a lot of "maybes" when doing a major version upgrade. CI2 to CI3 is pretty straight-forward for the most part and there's an actual migration guide that'll walk you through deprecated native functions and whatnot. Depending on what PHP functionality you use, some stuff may break (mainly because of the upgraded PHP version). Same goes for external libraries. My advice: run it on a test server with all logging and error reporting active and start seeing what needs updating. It's a pain, but it's better than doing it in production